# How to write a regex OR statement within strapply in R

Tags: r, regex

I have been using strapplyc in R to select different portions of a string that match one particular set of criteria.  These have worked successfully until I found a portion of the string where the required portion could be defined one of two ways.

Here is an example of the string which is liberally sprinkled with \t:

```
\t\t\tsome words here\t\t\tDefect: some more words here Action: more words
```

I can write the strapply statement to capture the text between Defect: and the start of Action:

```
strapplyc(record[i], "Defect:(.*?)Action")
```

This works and selects the chosen text between Defect: and Action.  In some cases there is no action section to the string and I've used the following code to capture these cases.

```
strapplyc(record[i], "Defect:(.*?)$")
```

What I have been trying to do is capture the text that either ends with Action, or with the end of the string (using $).

This is the bit that keeps failing.  It returns nothing for either option.  Here is my failing code:

```
strapplyc(record[i], "Defect:(.*?)Action|$")
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong, or a better solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to put the alternation inside a group, otherwise the first alternative is `Defect:(.*?)Action` and the second is `$`. You could rewrite it as `Defect:(.*?)(?:Action|$)`. A more efficient version of your regex would be `Defect:((?:[^A]|A(?!ction))*)`

Comment: If there is exactly one `Defect:` per line then removing everything up to Defect: and after Action: would also work: `gsub(".*Defect:|Action.*", "", x)` and allows `Action` to be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are up for a more efficient solution, you could drop the .*? matching and unroll your pattern like:

```
Defect:((?:[^A]+|A(?!ction))*)
```

This matches `Defect:` followed by any amount of characters that are not an `A` or are an `A` and not followed by `ction`. This avoids the expanding that is needed for the lazy dot matching. It will work for both ways, as it does stop matching when it hits `Action` or the end of your string.

As suggested by [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew), you can also use

```
Defect:([^A]*(?:A(?!ction)[^A]*)*)
```

Which is a little bit faster when there are many `A`s in the string.

You might want to consider to use `A(?!ction:)` or `A(?!ction\s*:)`, to avoid false early matches.

Comment: Good approach, I'd unroll it further as [`Defect:([^A]*(?:A(?!ction)[^A]*)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/Ugx3hS/1) if no word boundary check is necessary.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you. There was a mistake in my pattern (`[^A]` instead of `[^A]+`) which caused it to take many more steps. I have integrated your suggestion, as it seems to take a bit less steps, but isn't a huge dealbreaker any more.

Answer (score 1):

The alternation operator `|` is the regex operator with the lowest precedence. That means the regex `Defect:(.*?)Action|$` is actually a combination of `Defect:(.*?)Action` and `$` - since an empty string is a valid match for `$`, your regex returns the empty string.

To solve that, you should combine the regexes `Defect:(.*?)Action` and `Defect:(.*?)$` with an OR:

```
Defect:(.*?)Action|Defect:(.*?)$
```

Or you can enclose `Action|$` in a group as [Sebastian Proske said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39944692/how-to-write-a-regex-or-statement-within-strapply-in-r#comment67169687_39944692):

```
Defect:(.*?)(?:Action|$)
```